# How to configure TFS build agent with web proxy

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We noticed that one of our task started failing with the following error after using a new proxy:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 102.33.19.18:443

If we remove the proxy, everything back to the track. However, we already configured proxy for our build agent.

Are there something special we missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your self-hosted agent requires a web proxy, you can inform the agent about the proxy during configuration. This allows your agent to connect to Azure Pipelines or TFS through the proxy. This in turn allows the agent to get sources and download artifacts. Finally, it passes the proxy details through to tasks which also need proxy settings in order to reach the web.

To enable the agent to run behind a web proxy, pass --proxyurl, --proxyusername and --proxypassword during agent configuration.

For example:

```
./config.cmd --proxyurl http://127.0.0.1:8888 --proxyusername "myuser" --proxypassword "mypass"
```

**Note:** It applies to agent version 2.122 and newer. Do not forget to restart your agent and give it a try again.

Comment: How can i use this?